# What would be the maximum buffer limit while calling System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write()

Tags: c#, .net, networkstream

What would be the maximum buffer limit while calling

```
System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write((Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
```

method on a Windows 2003 32 bit machine.

Is it recommended to transfer large files using the above method.

Regards,
bse

Answer (score 1):

There is no limitation placed upon it so limitation is really just `Int32` (around 2GB) governed by size but it is only recommended to use small buffers (less than 1MB).

Comment: On a Windows XP 32-bit machine, with .Net **Compact** Framework 3.5 I'm experiencing IOException with a buffer of 242'743'296 bytes. The description on my machine is in Italian, but it sense is: "Insufficient buffer space or queue full. Impossible to perform the operation on socket"; _COMPlusExceptionCode = 0xe0434f4d.